Equo Chromium - SDK dependencies
Following my previous question here about Equo Chromium Community Edition, I managed to implement the browser in SWT thanks to Mauro Garcia's answer.
I am now trying to implement communication between Java and Javascript, and my question is the following :
communicating between Java and Javascript (especially triggering Java from Javascript), requires the comm API, which is part of the SDK, right ?
However, when I add the following dependency to my pom.xml file (as show in the getting started page), I get a 403 error :
  <dependency>
    <groupId>dev.equo</groupId>
    <artifactId>dev.equo.sdk</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2</version>
  </dependency>

  <repository>
    <id>chromium-swt-ee</id>
    <url>https://dl.equo.dev/chromium-swt-ee/equo-gpl/mvn</url>
  </repository>

Does that mean that the SDK is not included in the Community Edition ?
It does seem to be included according to this page, where they mention "Real-time Java / Javascript communication" in the 100% GPLv3 version
Here is the detailed error message I get :
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project test.equo: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.testmaven:test.equo:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies at dev.equo:dev.equo.sdk:jar:0.0.2 -> com.equo:com.equo.middleware.bom:jar:1.3.4: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.equo:com.equo.middleware.bom:jar:1.3.4: Could not transfer artifact com.equo:com.equo.middleware.bom:pom:1.3.4 from/to chromium-swt-ee (https://dl.equo.dev/chromium-swt-ee/equo-gpl/mvn): Access denied to https://dl.equo.dev/chromium-swt-ee/equo-gpl/mvn/com/equo/com.equo.middleware.bom/1.3.4/com.equo.middleware.bom-1.3.4.pom. Error code 403, -> [Help 1]


Am I missing something ? The two other dependencies for Equo Chromium (used in my original question referenced above), are also from https://dl.equo.dev/ and do not trigger that same problem.
